# PHP Passing Data to a Specific Class? (Data Encapsulation)

Tags: php

I've learned that OOP is all about data encapsulation, but what about passing data between classes that have nothing to do with each other (would the below example be worthy of using `extends`)?

```
class Dog {
    private $secretVar;

    public function getSecretVar() {
        $this->secretVar = 'psst... only for rainbow!';
        return $this->secretVar;
    }
}

class Rainbow {
    public function __construct(Dog $Dog) {
        print_r($Dog->getSecretVar());
    }
}

$Dog = new Dog();
$Rainbow = new Rainbow($Dog);

// ... classes that don't need the $secretVar
```

How would you encapsulate `$secretVar` for only classes `Dog` and `Rainbow`? As of now, anyone can call `getSecretVar()`, and I'm having a hard time allowing that to happen as it seems to defeat the whole point of encapsulation.

Comment: I will google that, I have never heard of it, I just started learning OOP

Comment: By the way, the variable should be editable (not static)

Comment: Uf, I'm afraid PHP doesn't have private classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution, although, it's ugly.

```
class Dog {
    private $secretVar = 'psst... only for rainbow!';    

    public function getSecretVar($caller == NULL) {

        // Here's the trick...
        if (get_class($caller) == 'Rainbow') {
            return $this->secretVar;
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    }
}

class Rainbow {
    public function __construct(Dog $Dog) {
        print_r($Dog->getSecretVar($this));
    }
}

$Dog = new Dog();
$Rainbow = new Rainbow($Dog);

// ... classes that don't need the $secretVar
```

It's ugly because it hard to maintain and not intuitive.  If you really need to do this, there's most likely a flaw in your design.

Comment: that's also a very smart answer. I think I don't really need to encapsulate this that far. Thank you for your time :D

Comment: I'm accepting this answer, since it doesn't use up "extends." It's a little messy, but it does encapsulate the data.

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't make sense for a Dog to extend Rainbow or vice versa just to share a variable.

What you are asking of may be possible but I don't know. If it was C++ using the `friend` visibility, it is certainly possible.

In this case, you have to make it `public` or use a getter and setter.

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulation is not ment to hide the value of the variable from the rest of the program but to have full control of how the rest of your program can access the variable.

By declaring the variable private you can check what values it can be set to and you can make changes to it before anybody reads it.

There is no real point in trying to let only some of the classes read the variable.

What you are trying to do could be achieved by using reflection to check which class and method calls the getSecretVar() method, but it's hardly ever useful.

Comment: "There is no real point in trying to let only some of the classes read the variable." I guess that's the answer. I guess I was taking encapsulation too far.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you could use `protected` like this: (every class that extends hasSecret will have access to it.)

```
<?php
class HasSecret {
    protected $secretVar = 'psst... only for rainbow!';
}

class Dog extends HasSecret {
    public function getSecretVar() {
        return $this->secretVar;
    }
}

class Rainbow extends HasSecret {
    public function __construct(Dog $Dog) {
        print_r($Dog->getSecretVar());
    }
}

$Dog = new Dog();
$Rainbow = new Rainbow($Dog);
```

Comment: I see, I failed to mention that the secret var is created in class `Dog`. I will edit my question.

Comment: @Adam184 In the Dog constructor, you can do: `$this->secretVar = "something else";`

Comment: :OOO that my friend is genius

Comment: it would mean that I wouldn't be able to use extends again, but in my case it works